# touchesBegan method not called when added as subview of another view

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Good evening.
I have two ViewControllers (lets name them A and B) both with method touchesBegan overriden. It works this way: when view A is tapped, the view of B is added as subview of view of A and appears with center placed at touch´s location. But when I tap in the view of B (recently added), touchesBegan of B is not called. I´ve already set view.enableUserInteraction to true in both views, already tested unsuccesfully nextResponder().touchesBegan method. What am I doing wrong ?
Obs: I intend to add several views of B (width=60, height=60) as subviews of view of A.

Answer (score 2):

This is because touch events were responded by A. You should turn off A's user interaction when B shows.

**Update:**
Try this:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (!self.clipsToBounds && !self.hidden && self.alpha > 0.01) {
        for (UIView *subview in self.subviews.reverseObjectEnumerator) {
            CGPoint subPoint = [subview convertPoint:point fromView:self];
            UIView *result = [subview hitTest:subPoint withEvent:event];
            if (result != nil) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: But I have to add several of B (width = 60 and height=60). If I turn A´s off, how do I add another B later?

Comment: @BrunoBarros I swe. You should override `hitTest` of A's view. When you found a subview was hit, you should deliver that event.

Comment: nice..could u help me on how to do that? I´d appreciate if u could answer with some code. tks

Comment: @BrunoBarros Updated my answer.

Comment: But when I add view of B as subview of view of A, the view of B is on the top of view of A. Theoretically, B was supposed to receive the touch with touchesBegan instead of view of A. Aint I right?

Comment: @BrunoBarros Google `ios response chain` and you'll find the reason. It's so long that I can't post it.

Comment: "The lowest view in the view hierarchy that contains the touch point becomes the hit-test view. After iOS determines the hit-test view, it passes the touch event to that view for handling" . In my case, wouldnt view of B the lowest view?

Comment: @BrunoBarros So A responded and won't deliver hit event any more.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have two views or two viewControllers? When you fire the event that loads view "B" call `.becomeFirstResponder()` on your view object.

Comment: Two viewControllers with their two respective views

Comment: you might have to add a gesture recognizer to your second view so it can handle the taps. `let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector()` 
        `view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)` then in the selector fire off whatever method you need.

Comment: Yes..I did that already and it worked well. But I just wanted to know why touchesBegan doesnt work. But tks btw

Comment: I actually found a great article describing what Lumailxk is talking about but don't have enough rep comment. Heres the link if you want to have a read [link](http://smnh.me/hit-testing-in-ios/) . Learn something new everyday.

Comment: tks, @Haligen..I read the article and still am confused. The article says that the hit test view returned ( In my case it would be B, because its overlaying A's view) handles the event. But A is handling the event ( I still dont know why). If I add a tap gesture in view of B, it works properly.